# Сервер возвращает ошибку "405 Method Not Allowed'

Tags: python, сервер, http, flask

Я запустил сервер на Flask. Но при запуске он возвращает ошибку в браузере ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.
Код server.py:

```py
import time
from datetime import datetime
from flask import Flask, Response, request

app = Flask(__name__)
db = []


@app.route("/send_message", methods=['POST'])
def send_message():
    data = request.json
    if not isinstance(data, dict):
        return Response('not json', 400)

    text = data.get('text')
    author = data.get('author')

    if isinstance(text, str) and isinstance(author, str):
        db.append({
            'text': text,
            'author': author,
            'time': time.time()
        })
        return Response('ok')
    else:
        return Response('wrong format', 400)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        app.run(host="127.0.0.1", port="5000", debug=False)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        exit(0)
```

В чем проблема и как ее исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас для пути `/send_message` разрешен только метод POST. Ошибка означает, что вы обращаетесь не методом POST, а каким-то другим. Когда вы открываете ссылку в браузере, по ссылке отправляется запрос GET. Нужно или реализовать реакцию на метод GET, или не пытаться открывать эту ссылку в браузере. Если вам нужно протестировать сервис, используйте Postman, например, и через него отправляйте POST запрос.